Is logger from elasticsearch.client deprecated?
I upgraded the elasticsearch package in my workspace, and now I'm getting a error from logger. Before, I could import logger from elasticsearch.client. But now, I get the following error : "cannot import name 'logger' from 'elasticsearch.client'".
Does logger became deprecated in the newest verion of elasticsearch API?
Thank you for every reply!

it is not there in documentation, hence it must be removed from latest version. it was part of 7.x version.
